# Merge subfolder directly into wwwroot

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

When i publish a Asp.Net core with angular app i get an unwanted folder under the wwwroot

[image]

But i want the content of that folder directly inside wwwroot.

I think the problem is in this piece of the project csproj file

```xml
<!--Include the newly-built files in the publish output--> 
<ItemGroup>
  <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />
  <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
    <RelativePath>wwwroot\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</RelativePath>
    <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
  </ResolvedFileToPublish>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: So the actual question is how to merge the contents into `wwwroot`, not that there's an unwanted folder. Why do you want to merge the folder? Does it contain scripts for Azure AD authentication? In that case it's better to have the module's files in a separate directory. In fact, any JS package manager would install and deploy modules in separate folders

Comment: the scripts for azure ad authentication are iside a angular component, I want that the angular build that I do when i publish ends directly inside wwwroot and not inside a folder

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: i have to depoy it on a azure webapp, if the content is inside another folder i can't read that, btw i solved it

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to change the "outDir" in the tsconfig.json

Comment: Can you share more detail? This looks like a comment and not a solution